# Adding controls dynamically to an UpdatePanel in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have the following really simple code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the codebehind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal literal = new Literal();
    literal.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    literal.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    // These both work fine the first time the button is clicked
    // but the second time nothing is added.
    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literal);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literal);
}
```

My problem comes in that the Literal control is only ever added once. I've scoured google and blog sites (plus books) but without any luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In asp.net, the controls in the ASPX file are automatically generated on each postback. The controls you've created are not in the ASPX code so the framework does not create them for you. The first time you execute the Button1_Click method, you add one extra control to the page. The second time you execute the Button1_Click method, you're on another post back and that first extra button has been forgotten about. So the result of that postback is you get one extra button again.

This will create one extra control each time you click the button (although the timestamps will update each time you press the button because the controls are being re-created)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (ViewState["ButtonCount"] != null)
    {
        count = (int)ViewState["ButtonCount"];
    }

    count++;
    ViewState["ButtonCount"] = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Literal literal = new Literal();
        literal.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        literal.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literal);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literal);
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree to the answer above, However this approach will not save the state of the dynamic controls (or to be accurate, it will save the state but not load them back).
Load view state is called in Load event section of page life cycle,where it assigns back the control values saved in view state.
However if the controls are not created by this time, They can not be loaded with previous data so for the state to be maintained, the new controls must be recreated on or before load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //PS: Below approach saves state as id is constant, it simply generates a new control with same id hence viewstate loads the value
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (ViewState["ButtonCount"] != null)
        {
            count = (int)ViewState["ButtonCount"];
        }

        count++;
        ViewState["ButtonCount"] = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            TextBox literal = new TextBox();
            //literal.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            literal.ID = "Textbox" + i.ToString();

            //UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literal);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literal);

        }
    }
}
```

[Dynamically adding controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback)
[View State and postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94696/in-asp-net-during-which-page-lifecycle-event-does-viewstate-get-loaded)

Comment: Agreed, this is better. Keeping the ID the same across postbacks allows the viewstate to apply correctly. Howver, this should be done in Init of the page as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx