# How to use PropertyProxyValidator with ServerSideValidationExtender at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, enterprise-library

I have added a `StringLenthValidator` attribute to the `name` field of my CSLA business object, with that I am trying to use the AJAX `PropertyProxyValidator` to server-validate the string inputs for that name field.

I was able to create the control at run-time and it worked fine, but it's not using the `PropertyProxyValidator` to report the Error Message that I specified in my Business Object attribute, instead it throws an error with the message below:

> Object is not valid and can not be
>   saved

Code Behind Below:

```
PropertyProxyValidator ppvNewName = new PropertyProxyValidator();
ppvNewName.PropertyName = "Name";
ppvNewName.ResourceClass = "MyResource";
ppvNewName.SourceTypeName = "SourceType";
ppvNewName.ControlToValidate = "txtNewName";
ppvNewName.Display = Dynamic;
ppvNewName.DisplayMode = List;
AjaxControlToolkit.WCSFExtensions.ServerSideValidationExtender ssve = new AjaxControlToolkit.WCSFExtensions.ServerSideValidationExtender();

ssve.TargetControlID = "ppvNewCategoryName";
```

Comment: Your code does not compile: `Display` and `DisplayMode` properties should both be enumerations. Also, there is no property called `ResourceClass` on `PropertyProxyValidator`.

Comment: You might take a look at this article: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=78. It shows how to add a `PropertyProxyValidator` to a page by using a simple extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the id of the `PropertyProxyValidator`?  You should set it and then call `ssve.TargetControlID = ppvNewName.ID`.

If you are doing this totally dynamically (besides wiring everything up properly) I think you are going to have to add your PropertyProxyValidator and ServerSideValidationExtender to your UpdatePanel.

Perhaps [Adding controls dynamically to an UpdatePanel in ASP.NET AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553073/adding-controls-dynamically-to-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-ajax) can be of some help for that.

Comment: I set the ID and followed all your suggestion but still the same issue. It's still not using the PropertyProxyvalidator to show the error specified in my Business Object attribute, but validating the string according to the length I specified works fine.