# How to add new ASP.NET table row by clicking button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net [ c# ] ..

My question is about adding new row; if I click on that button (like every time I click on that button it will add new row) .. 
I thought its easy to do it .. but it is not there. Something is missing I don't know what.

My code is [ Default3.aspx ] :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div align="center">     

<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell style="border-style:solid" >
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LABEL = 1 ">
           </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell style="border-style:solid" >
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="LABEL = 2 ">
           </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell style="border-style:solid" >
           <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="LABEL = 3 ">
           </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell style="border-style:solid" >
           <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="LABEL = 4 ">
           </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add More" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and for my C# [ Default3.aspx.cs ] :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TableRow NewRow1 = new TableRow();

    //1st cell
    TableCell NewCell1 = new TableCell();
    NewCell1.Style.Add("border-style","solid");

    // new lebel
    Label newLable1 = new Label();
    count = count + 1; // just for change number in label text 
    newLable1.Text = "NewLabel = "+ count;

    // adding lebel into cell
    NewCell1.Controls.Add(newLable1);

    // adding cells to row
    NewRow1.Cells.Add(NewCell1);

    //2ed cell
    TableCell NewCell2 = new TableCell();
    NewCell2.Style.Add("border-style", "solid");

    Label newLable2 = new Label();
    count = count + 1;
    newLable2.Text = "NewLabel = " + count;
    NewCell2.Controls.Add(newLable2);
    NewRow1.Cells.Add(NewCell2);

    //adding row into table
    Table1.Rows.Add(NewRow1);


}
```

I don't know what the problem is .. I even give each controls an IDs .. and I tried other ways but didn't work ..

Please if anyone can help me out .. I feel like am missing something important but I don't know what it is ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in the Question shared in [Walid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675754/447356), follow these steps:

1. Create a global list of table rows, something like:

   ```
   List<TableRow> TableRows
   ```
2. In button click Add the newly created row to list:

   ```
   TableRow row1=new TableRow();
   TableRows.add(row1);
   ```
3. In the `OnInit` method simply add all the rows to the table:

   ```
   foreach ( TableRow row in TableRows )
   {
       Table1.Rows.Add(row);
   }
   ```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Getting error- foreach statement can not operate on variable of type table because table does not contain public defination for getNumerator.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to persist the state of your control (table).

See a clear explanation to a very similar problem here    [ASP.NET dynamically created controls and Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback)

Comment: can u simple it for me .. i didn't understand any of it .. 
[if u don't mind] what ill do to make my example work right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add row just by using:

```
TableRow row1=new TableRow();
TableRows.add(row1);
```

But the concern is:

1. Clicked on Button, a row is added to table.
2. Clicked on the same button again then first row which you have already created no longer persists as ASP.NET is Stateless.

Solution: Ensure that on every button click, your already created rows data exists.