# Adding radiogroup, buttons and controls in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the complete code.   I want to display a radiogroup  when I select 1 in the dropdown list box. I get the error 'System.Web.HttpException: Control 'RadioButton1' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server'.

```
         namespace HostelRoomManagement 
         {
          public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
          {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

            }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
            rb1.ID = "RadioButton1";
            rb1.Text = "C block";
            rb1.GroupName = "BlockGroup";
            RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
            rb2.ID = "RadioButton2";
            rb2.Text = "C block";
            rb2.GroupName = "BlockGroup";
            Page.Controls.Add(rb1);
            Page.Controls.Add(rb2);



        }


    }

    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
}
```

I get the error 'System.Web.HttpException: Control 'RadioButton1' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server'

Comment: post your complete code please

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. In general to be able to help you more we need more information. E.g. when did you add the controls to the page etc.

Comment: @Brett I added the controls when I select a value from the dropdownlist box.

Comment: You do not have a Form tag <form runat=server> all the controls </form> or it is not runat=server... Or the dropdown is not inside the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the radio buttons you want the user to see based on his choice to the page and set the Visibility of them to false. Then, once the user choose a value change the visibility of the radio buttons you want to true. It might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have created two radio button but where have you added them on the page?

Start by creating a place holder for you radio-button lists and add these controls over there.
The dynamically created control will be lost on the post back. This means you will have to manage you dynamically created controls.

Here is a good [example]: [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i) [ASP.NET dynamically created controls and Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback).

Comment: I added these 2 lines and still no change.    Page.Controls.Add(rb1);
                Page.Controls.Add(rb2);

Comment: @krshekar System.Web.HttpException: Control 'RadioButton1' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server is the error I get

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you are referencing to `SelectedValue` whereas you want to be refering to `selectedindex`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No actually I checked with adding value to a label. It worked