# Dynamically Created Link Button Click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, linkbutton

I have a GridView .In this GridView we are dynamically generating columns . We     have  also   set Autogenerate columns to true in the GridView. Now the issue I am dynamically adding linkbutton to that columns .

**ISSUE** : 
      Link button click is not working .It is doing a postback and all the links are  disappeared.I have tried adding commands and click event but none of them are working. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code Behind** :

```
     protected void GridViewTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.DataItem != null && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {



                      for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {

                         LinkButton link = new LinkButton();


                         link.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;

                         link.EnableViewState = true;
                          link.Click += new EventHandler(onLinkClick);

                         e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(link);                  

                     }
                 }
            }



  protected void onLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }
```

**ASPX** :

```
 <asp:GridView
                            ID="GridViewTest"
                            runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                            CssClass="resultsTable"
                            Width="100%"
                            CellPadding="2"
                            CellSpacing="0"
                            GridLines="None"
                            autogenerateeditbutton="true"                                
                            OnRowDataBound="GridViewPullHistory_RowDataBound"
                            OnRowCreated="GridViewPullHistory_RowCreated">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridRow1" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="gridAltRow1" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" Font-Bold="true"  HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so what' s the problem? Any errors?

Comment: Link button click event is not working

Comment: "not working" is not an error-report. Be specific!

Comment: When i am clicking the links in the Gridview . I am not able to get the handle link button click event . Link Button Click is not excecuted in the postback .As a result all the links are gone and i also i am not able to get the value of the clicked link button .

Comment: AnyOne there? Sorry Christian Gartner for not so being specific

Comment: are you trying assign the link button to display? you have to set select link button to true

Comment: I believe in your page load you already code like this :         
         

   'if (!IsPostBack) {
 filldata()
     }'
      

but i still curious, you want to show modal popup extender by click the link, right ? why not to assign button in your pop up modal extender code?

Comment: Can you create the controls on Init? Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4218690/1193236

Answer (score 0):

Just register a PostBack trigger (since you are using an UpldatePanel):

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(link);
```