# Dynamically created checkbox find control doesn't work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing run time message page creation. Here I'm creating run time div with check box for each messages. But I'm using this one to get runtime.
`CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.FindControl(n) as CheckBox;`
But i can't get it.

Comment: Share the complete method code. To understand better.

Comment: And the aspx code with your CheckBox plz, to well understand your environment.

Comment: CheckBox ck = new CheckBox();
                ck.ID = getEmailWithout(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                child.Controls.Add(ck);
                
                ck.Attributes["class"] = "profilenameText";

Comment: This is My dynamic create code, but i'm getting respective id from my Database. But i cant access t

Comment: You provided very inappropriate information. Your code uses user defined functions, which are not mentioned. Kindly edit your post and provide aspx and aspx code information of the web form.

Comment: Sorry I cant upload that! Thats y am providing dis

Comment: can you please provide snippet of your code?

Comment: http://mockupr.com/mu/isii7273/page1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your dynamic control every time on `Page_Init` if you would like to access them after `Postback`.

See link below for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback) you can see the same problem.