# How can I check for the checkboxes that I've dynamically created in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

This is my code. The Problem is I can get the first set of checkboxes in the checbox1_checkedChanged() but not the second set.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     CheckBox checkthatBox= (CheckBox)sender;
        if (checkthatBox.Checked)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
                ch.ID = "ch" + i;
                ch.Text = "site "+i;
                ch.CssClass = "listItemWidth";
                ch.AutoPostBack= true;
                ch.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;
                ch.CheckedChanged += ch_CheckedChanged;
                sitesPanel.Controls.Add(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    void ch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("YO");
        CheckBox checkthatBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (checkthatBox.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
                ch.ID = "dl" + i;
                ch.Text = "Document Library " + i;
                ch.CssClass = "listItemWidth";
                ch.CheckedChanged += ch_CheckedChanged;
                docLibPanel.Controls.Add(ch);
            }
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: what is this function ch_CheckedChanged? can you make it more clear ?

Comment: That is the event handler for the checkboxes created in the CheckBox1_CheckedChanged function. I used the default one suggested by Visual Studio in the intellisense.

Comment: what does the gererated aspx code from the top function look like? Can you show us?

Comment: <input id="ch0" name="ch0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ch0\',\'\')', 0)" type="checkbox"><label for="ch0">site 0</label>

Comment: What's with the `throw new NotImplementedException();` bit? Is that still in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY setting

```
EnableViewState=false
```

of the dynamically created control

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Second set checkboxes are re-creating late in the page life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your dynamic control every time on `Page_Init` if you would like to access them or handle events from them after `Postback`.

See link below for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postbackhttp://) you can see the same problem.