# Event handling outside Page_Load or Page_Init

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events

Well if i'm creating an event programmatically and run it outside the `page_load` or `page_init` then it's not working. Do you have to write the code inside the `page_load` or `page_init`?

the code below is just a little example that works inside the page load or init but not outside.

```
    protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Add product";
        b.ID = "btn_Back";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        form1.Controls.Add(b);
    }
```

Comment: Where is this event handler registered?

Comment: You should review the page life cycle in ASP.NET.  This post may also help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback

Answer (score 0):

You can't add events outside the `Init` and `Load` events.

The `Page` object instance isn't persistent across calls, it is built every time you call that url, so every event handler added in another place than the `Page_Load` will be lost after the page content is sent.

Comment: Well i have created a method outside the page init or load that adds table rows with cells to a table control. I have added buttons  programmatically but the events aren't fired. The method is called each time i click to add a new row.

Comment: @user3512855: Because they aren't rebuilt when the page is created again and again on every postback.