# add row from asp.net code behind to htmltable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a new row to HtmlTable on click of button Add Row.
It adds one row. But it doesn't add further rows. Please advise.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="eLaundrySearchWeb.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
 </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table id="myTable" runat="server">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"   runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Row" OnClick="AddRow_Click" 
                                    />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
</div>
</form>
```

```
protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Random r=new Random();
        //int rv=r.Next(0,100);
        int numOfRows = myTable.Rows.Count;
        HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
        row.ID = "tbl_row"+(numOfRows+1);
        HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
        cell1.ID = "tbl_cell1"+ (numOfRows+1);
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.ID = "tbl_cell2" + (numOfRows + 1);
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbQty" + (numOfRows + 1);
        cell1.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        myTable.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is adding the rows every time you click the `button`.The only problem here is that the `button` is causing the `postback` and on `postback` the controls that were dynamically created are getting cleared.Then your `button` click event adds a row again.So it seems to you that the row is only added once.But in reality it is getting added everytime,it's just that on `postback` the earlier ones are getting cleared.
Trying converting your code into a function and call that function on `postback`.

**[Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553073/adding-controls-dynamically-to-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-ajax)**

Comment: looks like i need to handle all the rows again. Click for first time => add 1 row. click 2nd time=> add 2 rows..so on

Comment: @crazyTechie Ya you will need to keep track of the count using Viewstate , you can look at the question I referred to and may be do it accordingly.