# Literal Control text rendering doesn't work in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, literals

In my ASP.NET app I have Update Panel and Custom server control in it.

This Custom control has inside Literal Control. I try to set it's text property programmatically. But it doesn't render, because Literal Control is in Update Panel.

How can I solve this? Thanks very much.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanel">
<ContentTemplate>
    <st:AspGridViewTitlePanel runat="server" ID="GridTitle" Width="100%">                               
    </st:AspGridViewTitlePanel>     
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

AspGridViewTitlePanel - it's my server control. It has such code:

```
this.myLiteralControl = new LiteralControl();
this.myLiteralControl.Text = "Some text";
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void page_load(object sender, args e) {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    LiteralControl myLiteralControl = new LiteralControl();
    myLiteralControl.Text = @"<span> MY TEXT </span>";
    UP1.ContentTemplate.Controls.Add(myLiteralControl);
  }
}
```

[Adding controls dynamically to an UpdatePanel in ASP.NET AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553073/adding-controls-dynamically-to-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-ajax)

Comment: in my case:  updatepanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literalName);