# Right order to add/remove controls to updatepanel on update

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, init

I've been trying to add/remove controls to an updatepanel when updating it. Those controls are dynamically filled depending on the info in the page session.

The `Updatepanel_Load` event is triggered correctly but the controls I've changed won't show properly. They'll only show after a full postback!

Now I know that you need an `onInit` event to add / alter controls on the page but is this also necessary for an updatepanel? Can someone please explain the right order to do this?

ORDER RIGHT NOW:

- Button click
- LoginProcedure over ajax
- OnInit
- UpdatePanel1_Load (Generates controls)
- onInit.

So no controls are added / altered until full post back. What is the correct order / method to add / alter controls within an updatepanel without a full postback?

Comment: A short search on google gave me the following result:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553073/adding-controls-dynamically-to-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-ajax

Answer (score 0):

add async postback to your updatePanel like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Init..."></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBoxTrigger" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Adding a trigger has nothing to do with the thread synchronization between a handler and the page loading. i need the page load to wait until the external handler is complete.