# Dynamically created Button not calling event c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Button won't call it's event.

called in another button:

```
placeHolder.Controls.Add(CreateButton());
```

create button:

```
public Button CreateButton()
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "id";
    btn.Text = "some text";
    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    return btn;
}
```

Functionality:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do something.
}
```

places debug lines to find the source, it's simply not calling btn_Click() when clicked. What's missing?

Comment: have you tried to just add the method to the eventlist like: `btn.Click += btn_Click;`?

Comment: You have to add your button on every loading of the page, otherwise ASp.NET what's the source of the event that was fired

Comment: Doesn't work Sebastian, Andrei - I don't want the button there unless another button is clicked, so it's only put in the placeholder on another buttons event click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code prevents the click event from firing:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

Remove this code, or change it to:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return true;");
```

**EDIT**

I am tried this code and it worked correctly. `PlaceHolder` is in `form` tag and `runat` attribute is `server`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(CreateButton());
}

public Button CreateButton()
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "id";
    btn.Text = "some text";
    btn.Click += btn_Click;
    return btn;
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I put that in to prevent the post back from firing, removing/changing to true still doesn't fire the event: btn_Click

Comment: @thatguy see may edited answer. I am tested this with `VS2013`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to load through Page_Load instead of through a another button, and simply set it's visibility property in the button - Accepted.

Comment: How to stop the postback?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that just checks if it is a postback - instead of preventing it on the button.

Comment: @thatguy are you want no postback when button clicked?

Comment: Yea that's the idea, the btn_Click is called now, but prevention of postback has been removed.

Comment: If you want no postback you should write click codes at `javascript` and `return false`. But if you want write click codes at `c#` you should use `UpdatePanel`. If you ask another question about this I will answer with my codes.

Comment: See information about UpdatePanel -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553073/adding-controls-dynamically-to-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-ajax)